# Submitting Laravel Livewire form via http or guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle, laravel-livewire

There are a few components to my question.

1. Does Livewire have an easy way to get all form elements in a form including image file uploads as well as dynamic form fields that will come in as an array.
2. I've seen a lot of "contact us" Livewire form examples but none where the form submits to an external API. The http equivalent of `<form method="POST" action="apiplace.com/submit">`. However I don't want to leave the page.

Right now my form submits this way:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

However in my submit function I need to send all the data from the form to an API via POST, retrieve the response and display success or any errors to the end user.

Comment: You can use the `Http` facade in your `submit` method to perform the external request, which is pretty well documented - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client

Comment: what you get as data in $request object pass it to Laravel Http Client of post method

Answer (score 0):

In your submit_form.blade.php file :

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
    <input type="file" wire:model="username">
    <input type="file" wire:model="photo">
    <button type="submit">Save Form</button>
</form>
```

In your livwire component file :

```
class SubmitForm extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $photo, $username;

    public function submit()
    {
         $file               = $this->photo;
         $file_path          = $file->getPathname();
         $file_mime          = $file->getMimeType('image');
         $file_uploaded_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

       $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://example.com/api/upload', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
             'filename' => $file_uploaded_name,
             'Mime-Type'=> $file_mime,
             'contents' => fopen($file_path, 'r'),

        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'username',
            'contents' => $this->username
        ]
     ],
    ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain your code, and not just dump some code. There are also some undefined variables. missing imports and lacks error handling.